# Cropping not working in Nexus 5,Device Version 5.1.1

Tags: android, crop

I want to get an image from gallery or camera and then I want to crop it in a particular aspect ratio.
But this code is working in Lollipop Version whereas it works in KitKat.
Can anyone plse helpme to solve this Problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
ImageView imgview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button buttonCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_take_camera);
    Button buttonGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select_gallery);
    buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
    // call android default camera
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
                    // ******** code for crop image
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 2);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);


            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);


        }
    });
    buttonGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //// //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            // call android default gallery
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // ******** code for crop image
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 2);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);


            try {

                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // Do nothing for now
            }
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
        imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);


    }

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
        if (extras2 != null) {
            Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
            imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting extras2 as null in the last part right?

Same is happening with me! Could you explain what happens precisely? Does it crash the Photos app or you don't see the update in your imageView?